# Why this recursive code repeated infinite?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm just calculating with recursive code, but it goes into infinite loop.

**EDIT:** Full code. 
and IDE(Eclipse) says nothing about it, and it can be running well.

```
class RepresentWithN {
    static int number;
    static int N;
    static int answer;

public int solution(int N, int number) {
    RepresentWithN.N = N;
    RepresentWithN.number = number;
    answer = 9;

    calc(0, 0);
    return answer == 9 ? -1 : answer;
}

static int conN(int length) {
    int tmp = N;
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        tmp += tmp * 10;
    }
    return tmp;
}

static void calc(int prev, int count) {
    if (count == 9) {
        return;
    }

    if (prev == number) {
        answer = Math.min(answer, count);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("count=" + count + " prev=" + prev);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        calc(prev + conN(i), count + 1);
        calc(prev - conN(i), count + 1);
        calc(prev * conN(i), count + 1);
        calc(prev / conN(i), count + 1);
    }
}
```

It repeated 'count' is around 7 or 8, and don't know why.

Comment: Your favorite IDE's debugger can quickly give you the answer. What information does it give you when you run the program through the debugger?

Comment: wait for another few more minutes or hours. eventually count will be 9.

Comment: @ruhul I waited for few miniutes, but It doesn't stop.

Comment: Where is the main function you are using to call this? Please add this as well. It currently ends for me after changing solution to a static method and calling it with ```solution(0, 0)```, so I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @TreyGraham That is another class file, and it's just simple code about new object of this class and print object.solution(2, 11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually `count` has the value `9`. check this by printing this values.

```
static void calc(int prev, int count) {
        System.out.println("count=" + count + " prev=" + prev);
        if (count == 9) {
            return;
        }
        ...
```

There are so many branches in your recursion and that needs a huge amount of calculation. Thats why it is not ending. You can wait another hour or days/years to see the ends of this program. Or replace this code with efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  After each run, uncomment one of the recursive calls.

```java
public class ForEverDemo {

   static long count = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      alongtime(0);
      System.out.println("count = " + count);
   }

   public static void alongtime(int v) {
      count++;
      if (v == 9) {
         return;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         alongtime(v + 1);
         // alongtime(v + 1);
         // alongtime(v + 1);
         // alongtime(v + 1);
         // alongtime(v + 1);
      }
   }
}
```